# Spark: How do I get the WebSocket instance?

Tags: spark-java

In Spark (sparkjava), when I annotate @WebSocket it works [as documented](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#websockets) for me. Great :)

However. Since the my annotated class instance is created by the framework - I loose control over it. I would like to be able to inject services/repositories into the actual WebSocket instance. Or inject the websocket instance into a service.

The only way I've figured I can communicate to it currently, is though static context, which I find messy.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following method (tested with Spark 2.5.5):

https://static.javadoc.io/com.sparkjava/spark-core/2.5.5/spark/Spark.html#webSocket-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

Using this you can call `Spark.webSocket("/bla", new WebSocketHandler());`
Where WebSocketHandler would be your annotated class.

This seems to have been added in [this](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/commit/6f29dc5b611643d997093f46c2c2c0794ee5b022) pull request.